# Firestore Android usage calculator

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore with Android. I want to know how Firestore is being used by my single android device. I mean, if I perform a single action from my device how could I know Firestore read, write or delete are being used. I can't check from Firestore usage tab, because It is also being used by iOS, front end and backend server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't provide any sort of logging or auditing to know where reads and writes are coming from.  That's something you'll have to log in your app, if you want to know how it behaves.

Comment: Is it possible from Google Cloud Console?

Comment: Not without you logging the information from your application code. Firestore doesn't track usage on a per-user level.